# How can I show the "no data" toast if there is nothing in database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show some text like "there is nothing to remove" with Toast. However, I have no idea where to check the current data status (empty or not) and show the user message. I would be really appreciated your help if you guys can suggest anything.

Here is my code

```
DatabaseReference myRefC = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Wishlist");
        myRefC.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    postSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                    overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataSnapshot`'s `hasChildren()` method to check if any `item` is available to remove , else you can show `Toast`

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
     if(!snapShot.hasChildren()){ //no children show toast
         Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "There is nothing to remove", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
     }
     for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
           postSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
           Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           finish();
           overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
           startActivity(getIntent());
           overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Sir is said "Cannot resolve symbol 'postSnapshot" @rajan.kali

Comment: sorry :D @a_local_nobody